# How to initialize variables, compile and run GNU assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu

How do you intialize variables in GNU x86? And how do you compile and run them? I've searched everywhere but I can't find a proper tutorial. Here's my code. I'm also not sure whether my syntax is correct or not since I still can't test them

```
section .data 
    number db 'Enter ten numbers: ', 10
    numberLen equ $-number
    i dw 0 

section .bss
    digits resw 10

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    movw $0, %esi

    movl $4, %eax 
     movl $1, %ebx 
     movl $number, %ecx 
     movl $32, %edx
    int $0x80

    for:
        cmpsw $10, (%i)
        jge skip
        movl $3, %eax 
            movl $0, %ebx
        lea digits(%esi), %ecx
        movl $2, %edx
        int $0x80
        subw $0x30, digits(%esi)
        incw %esi
        incw %i
        jmp for
    skip:
        pushw %digits
        pushw %i
        call sort
        movb $0, %esi
            movw $0, %i
            print:
                cmpsw $10, (%i)
                jge exit
                addw $0x30, digits(%esi)
                movl $4, %eax 
                movl $1, %ebx 
                lea digits(%esi), %ecx
                movl $1, %edx
                int $0x80
                incw %esi
                incw %i
                jmp print
    exit:
        movl $1, %eax 
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80

    sort:
        movw %esp, %ebp
        movb $0, %esi
        for2:
            movw $0, %edi
            cmpsw $10, (%esi)
            jge after
            for3:
                movw digits(%edi), %al
                cmpsw (%edi), (%esi)

                jl cmp2
                cmp1:
                    cmpsw (%al), digits(%esi)
                    jmp continue

                cmp2:
                    cmpsw digits(%esi), (%al)
                continue:
                    jge next
                    movw digits(%esi), %bl

                    movw digits(%edi), %al
                    movw %al, digits(%esi)
                    movw %bl, digits(%edi)
                next:

                    cmpsw $10, (%esi)
                    jge next2
                    incw %edi
                    jmp for3
            next2:
                incw %esi
                jmp for2
        after:  
                ret 6
```

Comment: _"How do you intialize variables in GNU x86? And how do you compile and run them?"_ You don't compile or run a variable. You assemble your assembly code into object code, which you then link into an executable that you can run. Can you point to the specific line(s) that you're unsure about?

Comment: If you can comment your code (a comment for each line is generally considered best)  we will have a much easier time of understanding it and helping you.  At present, I can't tell what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Initialising variables**

You can initialise variables in your `.data` section.  You usually do it like this:

`label: .directive values...`

For example, `listofnumbers: .byte 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

There is a [list of "pseudo-ops"](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html#Pseudo-Ops) which includes the data definition directives like `.ascii`, `.byte`, and so on.

You refer to the address of `listofnumbers` in your code using `$listofnumbers` and the value at the address using `listofnumbers`.  So `movl $listofnumbers, %eax` would put the address of `listofnumbers` in the `eax` register, and `movb listofnumbers, %al` would put the literal value `1` in the lower byte of the `eax` register.

**Compiling your code**

To compile `filename.S` into executable `filename`, I recommend:

`gcc -nostdlib -g -o filename filename.S`

`-nostdlib` stops gcc trying to link standard library routines that will look for a `main` function.

`-g` compiles the code with debugging symbols.  This means you can run the code with gdb (`gdb filename`), set breakpoints, and step through the code (e.g. `break 1`, `run`, `step` once inside gdb).  In gdb, `info reg` and `x/100xw $ebp-50` will let you look at registers and the area in memory around the stack.

You can run your code with a simple `./filename`, but I recommend `gdb` because it will make it a *lot* easier to see what is going on when you get unexpected results.

Comment: I'm getting a segmentation fault at this part, subw $0x30, digits(%esi). What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your code above doesn't even compile for me (it looks like a mix of NASM and GAS syntax, so I'm not surprised).  That makes it hard to tell what your error is.  A segmentation fault usually indicates that you tried to perform an operation on memory you should not have been touching.